# SegV exception when clock rate is configured on a serial connection on a Cisco 2611 XM router

Tags: cisco, router

The IOS I have is:

```
Cisco IOS Software, C2600 Software (C2600-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(25d), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
```

I have a card installed with four serial ports.  Whenever I have any serial interface that has been `no shut` and has the clock rate set (and the dte side has also been `no shut`), I get a SegV exception like below.

```
main(config-if)#clock rate 64000
main(config-if)#

00:14:55 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002: Unexpected exception to CPUvector 100, PC = 0x80519C70, LR = 0x80246E34

-Traceback= 0x80519C70 0x80246E34 0x80247378 0x8024FB90

CPU Register Context:
MSR = 0x00009032  CR  = 0x33000033  CTR = 0x8228635C  XER   = 0xA000E77F
R0  = 0x00000000  R1  = 0x84C5EB78  R2  = 0x84680000  R3    = 0x00000001
R4  = 0x00000038  R5  = 0x84BE96F8  R6  = 0x84680000  R7    = 0x68010000
R8  = 0x00000000  R9  = 0x00000000  R10 = 0x84420000  R11   = 0x84A4176C
R12 = 0x0003D738  R13 = 0xFFF4B634  R14 = 0x804F2CE0  R15   = 0x00000000
R16 = 0x00000000  R17 = 0x848743C4  R18 = 0x00000000  R19   = 0x00000000
R20 = 0x0000000F  R21 = 0x84680000  R22 = 0x84870000  R23   = 0x00000000
R24 = 0x800A8FE0  R25 = 0x9EA0612C  R26 = 0x0467D2D8  R27   = 0x848743C4
R28 = 0x84870000  R29 = 0x000F4240  R30 = 0x00000000  R31   = 0x00000000

Writing crashinfo to flash:crashinfo_20020301-001455

=== Flushing messages (00:14:55 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002) ===

Queued messages:
*** System received a SegV exception ***
signal= 0xb, code= 0x100, context= 0x84874190
PC = 0x80519c70, Vector = 0x100, SP = 0x84c5eb78
*** Unexpected Console tx-ready interrupt ***
PC = 0xfff03fc4, Vector = 0x500, SP = 0x84875334

System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(8r) [cmong 8r], RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Copyright (c) 2003 by cisco Systems, Inc.
```

Crash info file:

```
Router#more flash:/crashinfo_20020301-001455
*Mar  1 00:00:07.572: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface VoIP-Null0, changed state to up
This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:
ww.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export---cisco.com.

Cisco 2611XM (MPC860P) processor (revision 3.1) with 127205K/3867K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FOC08290ENT
M860 processor: part number 5, mask 2
2 FastEthernet interfaces
4 Low-speed serial(sync/async) interfaces
32K bytes of NVRAM.
49152K bytes of processor board System flash (Read/Write)



     --- System Configuration Dialog ---

Would you like to enter the initial configuration dialog? [yes/no]:
*Mar  1 00:00:33.238: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:33.238: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:33.238: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial1/0, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:33.238: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial1/1, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:33.242: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial1/2, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:33.242: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial1/3, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:34.240: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:34.240: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:34.240: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/0, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:34.240: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/1, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:34.244: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/2, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:34.244: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/3, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:00:54.252: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/1, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:54.252: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/2, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:00:54.256: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/3, changed state to down
*Mar  1 00:01:00.911: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to upno
CMD: 'access-list 199 permit icmp host 10.10.10.10 host 20.20.20.20' 00:12:01 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'crypto map NiStTeSt1 10 ipsec-manual' 00:12:01 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'match address 199
' 00:12:01 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'set peer 20.20.20.20
' 00:12:01 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'exit' 00:12:01 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'no access-list 199' 00:12:01 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'no crypto map NiStTeSt1' 00:12:02 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002

*Mar  1 00:12:03.091: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:12:03.091: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface FastEthernet0/1, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:12:03.095: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Serial1/0, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:12:03.095: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Serial1/1, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:12:03.095: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Serial1/2, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:12:03.095: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Serial1/3, changed state to administratively down
*Mar  1 00:12:03.796: %SYS-5-RESTART: System restarted --
Cisco IOS Software, C2600 Software (C2600-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(25d), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2010 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 18-Aug-10 04:49 by prod_rel_team
*Mar  1 00:12:03.796: %SNMP-5-COLDSTART: SNMP agent on host Router is undergoing a cold start
*Mar  1 00:12:04.093: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/0, changed state to downCMD: 'en' 00:12:37 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'conf t' 00:12:40 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'hostname main' 00:12:43 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'do write mem' 00:12:49 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'write mem' 00:12:49 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'config-' 00:13:48 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'config-register 0x2102' 00:13:51 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'int s1/1' 00:13:59 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'clock rate 64000' 00:14:04 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'no clock rate' 00:14:08 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.252' 00:14:19 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'no shut' 00:14:21 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002

*Mar  1 00:14:23.068: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Serial1/1, changed state to up
*Mar  1 00:14:24.070: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/1, changed state to upCMD: 'ping 10.0.0.2' 00:14:32 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'do ping 10.0.0.2' 00:14:36 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002
CMD: 'ping 10.0.0.2' 00:14:36 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002

*Mar  1 00:14:46.823: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Serial1/1, changed state to down

00:14:55 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002: Unexpected exception to CPUvector 100, PC = 0x80519C70, LR = 0x80246E34

-Traceback= 0x80519C70 0x80246E34 0x80247378 0x8024FB90

CPU Register Context:
MSR = 0x00009032  CR  = 0x33000033  CTR = 0x8228635C  XER   = 0xA000E77F
R0  = 0x00000000  R1  = 0x84C5EB78  R2  = 0x84680000  R3    = 0x00000001
R4  = 0x00000038  R5  = 0x84BE96F8  R6  = 0x84680000  R7    = 0x68010000
R8  = 0x00000000  R9  = 0x00000000  R10 = 0x84420000  R11   = 0x84A4176C
R12 = 0x0003D738  R13 = 0xFFF4B634  R14 = 0x804F2CE0  R15   = 0x00000000
R16 = 0x00000000  R17 = 0x848743C4  R18 = 0x00000000  R19   = 0x00000000
R20 = 0x0000000F  R21 = 0x84680000  R22 = 0x84870000  R23   = 0x00000000
R24 = 0x800A8FE0  R25 = 0x9EA0612C  R26 = 0x0467D2D8  R27   = 0x848743C4
R28 = 0x84870000  R29 = 0x000F4240  R30 = 0x00000000  R31   = 0x00000000


=== Start of Crashinfo Collection (00:14:55 UTC Fri Mar 1 2002) ===

For image:
Cisco IOS Software, C2600 Software (C2600-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(25d), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2010 by Cisco Systems, Inc. 
Compiled Wed 18-Aug-10 04:49 by prod_rel_team

FF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
8525D9DC: FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
8525D9FC: FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
8525DA1C: FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
8525DA3C: FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
8525DA5C: FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
8525DA7C: FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
```

It just keeps having SegV exceptions and restarting if I don't put it into rommon mode and start over without that config.

There is also about 1400 more lines of memory addresses (that goes at the end of what I pasted), etc, in the crash info file, but I decided to not paste them.

Does anybody know what could be wrong or how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Call Cisco. I'd say check the system's memory. The 2600 is *way* EOL, so you aren't going to like the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was just a faulty Serial WIC.